# artisan - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'

Tags: mysql, laravel, terminal, laravel-artisan

I ran the command: "php artisan migrate" and got the error message displayed below:

```
 [PDOException]                                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: make sure your database config set on env file is correct and that mysql server is up and running.

Answer (score 4):

there could be following possibilities -

- you haven't set the right credentials for mysql access in your .env file which is located at the root of your application.

**Solution** - Open .env file in your preferred editor and check if all the mysql access credentials are correct.

its something like -

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=[your db name here]
DB_USERNAME=[db user here]
DB_PASSWORD=[password]
```

- the user credentials doesn't have access to mysql or database that you mentioned in .env file

**Solution** - use any mysql interface (phpmyadmin, workbench..etc) to check if the user that you mentioned in .env file have enough access to connect.

- mysql is not running - based on your OS(windows, ubuntu..) check if mysql is running

Comment: My mysql server wasn't running. Thanks.