# Laravel 5.1. cannnot run artisan commands

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 and I cannot run any artisan commands.

I uploaded my project to our live server with PHP5.5.22 CLI version.

everytime I run artisan commands I am getting this error
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (146)`

I changed the configuration on my .env and config/database.php files to point to our MySQL server.

**.env file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=****.sddb0040291787.*****
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sddb0040291787
DB_USERNAME=sddbMTcyNjEy
DB_PASSWORD=**********
```

**config/database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '****.sddb0040291787.*****'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'sddb0040291787'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sddbMTcyNjEy'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '**********'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

even `php artisan config:cache` command doesn't work and returns same error.

Appreciate any help. Thanks guys!

Comment: use the -vvv flag with artisan to output more detail about error

Comment: I got the error, it still looking for the database in our local development server even though I changed the configuration already on .env and database.php files.

Comment: any idea why it still looking for the database in my local server?

Answer (score 0):

This may give you some ideas, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37005818/8825233

Check if MySQL server is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **--env=production** to your artisan command

Please ensure that it is the right DB information which is stored in the env-file. By default it is localhost which is stored in the env.

Or you could simply delete the **env()** function from your config if you dont want to use enviroment variables. Like :

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '****.sddb0040291787.*****',
        'database'  => 'sddb0040291787',
        'username'  => 'sddbMTcyNjEy',
        'password'  => '**********',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Comment: If he didn't stored the DB information in the env-file and just let i keeped as when it was created original, the MySQL attempts to connect to localhost. 
This is not an workaround, but a solution for his problem.